# Django. Авторизация через одну из моделей пользователя

Tags: django

Имеется 2 таблицы в базе с разными пользователями и соответственно 2 модели для них. На сайте имеется 2 разные формы с авторизацией пользователя, одни которые сами регистрировались и что то заказывали, другие это клиенты магазина с дисконтной картой, пользователи из разных таблиц никак не связаны. Вопрос таков, как можно выбрать динамически нужную модель для авторизации, с использованием встроенного механизма авторизации в Django.

Пока что я смотрю в сторону создания третьей основной модели пользователя именно для авторизации в которой будет просто храниться название одной из двух таблиц и идентификатор для связи пользователя, тоесть при авторизации будет создаваться запись в эту таблицу, а через эту запись уже будут получаться данные из нужной таблицы название которой мы храним.

**УТОЧНЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ**

Про то как все устроено и почему 2 таблицы спрашивать не надо, не в этом вопрос, приведено просто для понимания задачи.

Вопрос заключается в том что - **можно ли при авторизации выбрать конкретную модель пользователя**.

Просто кастомная модель пользователя для авторизации прописывается в настройках сайта и она много где используется системой, в этом для меня оказалась трудность, вот хотелось узнать можно ли както это обойти.

Comment: Решил расширить таблицу с пользователями которые регистрируются сами, добавил в ней связку с пользователями с дисконтом, и сделал ее основной. При регистрации пользователя через дисконтную карту будет проверяться запись в основной таблице, если ее нет то создается. Но вопрос остается открытым о возможности переключения между 2 моделями авторизации.

Comment: Не-не, давайте с самого начала: зачем пользователи вообще разделены на две (а с промежуточной — даже три) таблицы?

Comment: @andreymal это уже было так давно сделано, еще до меня и вообще на 2 языках perl и php, на одном работал сайт где пользователи сами регистрировались и делали покупки, вторая система была внедрена сильно позже, там уже хранились клиенты из 1С и у них есть дисконт, нужно из всего это говна сделать нормальный новый сайт, но база и все ее таблицы естественно останутся старые, там дофига таблиц и данных. Новый сайт на Django делаю, и нужно все объединить в едино, но надо чтобы клиенты которые сами регались и входили под своим аккаунтом, а клиенты которые с дисконтом регались уже отдельно.

Comment: Вопрос не в этой всей системе, как что устроено. Вопрос в том, есть ли возможность при авторизации выбрать одну из двух моделей для пользователя.

Comment: Мне кажется, такой возможности скорее всего не найдётся, потому что в этом как раз нет смысла :) Я бы на вашем месте продумал возможности переноса данных в новые таблицы, с одной моделью пользователей ("отдельным регистрациям" это никак не мешает, всю нужную информацию можно записать в дополнительных полях)

Comment: «как все устроено и почему 2 таблицы спрашивать не надо» — нет, надо, потому что [ошибка XY — частая беда у новичков](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709) :) Нет смысла отвечать на вопрос, как микроскопом забивать гвозди, когда можно просто взять молоток. Конечно, похоже, это не ваш случай (не вы изобрели две таблицы всё-таки), но всё же советую вам готовиться к тому, что возможности выбрать модель не найдётся и придётся искать альтернативные пути решения задачи.

Comment: @andreymal не в текущем варианте, мне был важен именно механизм джанги с 2 моделями, проблему то я конечно решил уже как и писал в комменте выше, путем расширения таблицы. Ну и новичек это не ко мне, я программирую уже 10 лет, просто впервые столкнулся с такой задачей думал вдруг кто делал похожее. Мне не нужно решать текущую задачу, я ее уже решил, мне нужно знание в копилку ))